# Error CS0019 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'HttpStatusCode' and 'int'

Tags: c#, compilation

Hello I am trying to compile a program I made but I ran into an error which I don't know how to fix. I have tried every solution I can come up with and want to see if anybody can help me fix it
Here is the code where the error occurs.

```
string text4 = string.Format("X-XSRF-TOKEN={0}&X-XSRF-URI=%2Flogin%2FdoLauncherLogin&fromForm=yes&authType=&linkExtAuth=&epic_username={1}&password={2}&rememberMe=YES", attributeValue, arg, arg2);
httpRequest.Cookies = httpResponse.Cookies;
xNet.HttpResponse httpResponse2 = httpRequest.Post("", text4, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
if (httpResponse2.StatusCode == 200)
{
    ref int ptr = ref this.int_0;
    this.int_0 = ptr + 1;
    ptr = ref this.int_2;
    this.int_2 = ptr + 1;
    backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(0, text);
    if (this.bool_0)
    {
          this.queue_1.Enqueue(text2);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could cast the enum to `int` if you want to retain your approach [`if ((int)httpResponse2.StatusCode == 200)`]. If not, I suggest using the `HttpStatusCode` enum.

Answer (score 1):

Use enum [`HttpStatusCode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
if (httpResponse2.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man this sorted it out really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

You should use the corresponding **[Enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode(v=vs.110).aspx)** value

```
if (httpResponse2.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use the `HttpStatusCode` enumeration rather than just the status code as an integer. So

`httpResponse2.StatusCode == 200`

should become

`httpResponse2.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK`.